# I deleted one of the data in the table based on id, but what was deleted was another id whose value is smaller

Tags: laravel, eloquent, crud, delete-row

I have started learning Laravel framework since 2 weeks ago.

Here, I have 2 tables, namely anggotas and simpanans
which has one-to-many relationship,
one anggota (id_anggota as pk) can have many simpanan(id simpanan as pk).
I have used id_anggota as a foreign key in the simpanans table, but
when I delete one of the rows in the simpanans table based on id, it deletes another id whose value is smaller.

this is the models in Simpanan model

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

   class Simpanan extends Model
   

   {
    use HasFactory;

    // protected $table='simpanans';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_simpanan';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'no_anggota','tgl','tabungan','s_wajib','s_thr','s_pendidikan','lain','catatan'
    ];

    public function anggota(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Anggota::class);
    }
    
}
```

this is the models in Anggota model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Anggota extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_anggota';
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_anggota','name','tmlahir','tglahir','alamat','ktp','pendidikan','pekerjaan','hp',
    ];

    public function detailAnggota($id){
        return DB::table('anggotas')->where('id_anggota', $id)->first();
    }

    public function simpanan(){
        return $this->hasMany(Simpanan::class,'no_anggota','id_anggota');
    }

}
```

this the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Simpanan;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\View\Concerns\ManagesLayouts;

class SimpananController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('layouts.simpanan.simpanan');
    }
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Simpanan = new Simpanan();
    }

    public function simpan(){
        $data=[
            'simpanan'=>$this->Simpanan->joinAnggota()
        ];
            return view('layouts.simpanan.simpanan',$data);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $rules=[
            'id_anggota'=>'required',
            'tglsetor'=>'required',
            'tabungan'=>'required',
            's_wajib'=>'required',
            's_thr'=>'required',
            's_pendidikan'=>'required',
            'lain'=>'required',
            'catatan'=>'nullable'
        ];
        $messages = [
            'tglsetor.required'=> 'Tanggal harus diisi!!!',
            'tabungan.required'=> 'Tabungan harus diisi dengan angka, atau diisi dengan angka 0 !!!',
            's_wajib.required'=> 'Simpanan Wajib harus diisi dengan angka, atau diisi dengan angka 0 !!!',
            's_thr.required'=> 'Simpanan THR harus diisi dengan angka, atau diisi dengan angka 0 !!!',
            's_pendidikan.required'=> 'Simpanan Pendidikan harus diisi dengan angka, atau diisi dengan angka 0 !!!',
            'lain.required'=> 'Dana Lain harus diisi dengan angka, atau diisi dengan angka 0 !!!',
        ];
 
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
         
        if($validator->fails()){
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput($request->all());
        }

        $simpan = new Simpanan();
        $simpan->anggota_id_anggota = $request->id_anggota;
        $simpan->tgl = $request->tglsetor;
        $simpan->tabungan = $request->tabungan;
        $simpan->s_wajib = $request->s_wajib;
        $simpan->s_thr = $request->s_thr;
        $simpan->s_pendidikan = $request->s_pendidikan;
        $simpan->lain = $request->lain;
        $simpan->catatan = $request->catatan;
        $simpan->save();
        return redirect('/simpanan')->with('status','Data berhasil ditambahkan');

    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $simpanan=Simpanan::find($id);
        return view('layouts.simpanan.edit',['simpanan'=>$simpanan]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        
        $simpanan=Simpanan::find($id);
        $simpanan->update([
            'tgl'=>$request->tglsetor,
            'tabungan'=>$request->tabungan,
            's_wajib'=>$request->s_wajib,
            's_thr'=>$request->s_thr,
            's_pendidikan'=>$request->s_pendidikan,
            'lain'=>$request->lain,
            'catatan'=>$request->catatan
        ]);
        return redirect('/simpanan')->with('status','Data Berhasil Dirubah');
        
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $simpanan=Simpanan::findOrFail($id)->where('id_simpanan',$id);
        $simpanan->delete();
        return redirect('/simpanan')->with('status','Data Berhasil Dihapus');
    }

}
```

and this the view

```
<section class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h3 class="card-title">History Simpanan</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body">
                  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">No.</th>
                        <th scope="col">ID Transaksi</th>
                        <th scope="col">Tanggal</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nomor Anggota</th>
                        <th scope="col">Nama</th>
                        <th scope="col">Tabungan</th>
                        <th scope="col">S. Wajib</th>
                        <th scope="col">S. THR</th>
                        <th scope="col">S. Pendidikan</th>
                        <th scope="col">Aksi</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    @php $no=1; @endphp
                    @foreach ($simpanan as $data)
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$no++}}</td>
                        <td>STR{{$data->id_simpanan}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->tgl}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->id_anggota}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->tabungan}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->s_wajib}}</td>
                        <td>{{$data->s_thr}}</td>
                        <td><span class="badge bg-danger">{{$data->s_pendidikan}}</span></td>
                        <td>
                          <div class="text-right">
                            <a href="/simpanan/edit/{{$data->id_simpanan}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">
                              <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Edit
                            </a>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-sm">
                              <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Hapus
                            </button>
                          </div>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    @endforeach
                  </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="modal-sm">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Yakin hapus data?</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Data yang dihapus tidak dapat kembali&hellip;</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
                        <a href="/simpanan/hapus/{{$data->id_simpanan}}" methode="post" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                          <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Hapus
                        </a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                  </div>
                  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal -->
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">{{$simpanan->links()}}</div>
              </div>
              <!-- /.card -->
            <!-- /.col -->
            </div>
          <!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </section>
      <!-- /.content -->
```

Comment: Is it deleting the wrong simpanan or the wrong anggotas?

Comment: its wrong simpanan

Comment: Is it your route for deletion ? "href="/simpanan/hapus/{{$data->id_simpanan}}"

Comment: in view yes...
in route web.php 
Route::get('/simpanan/hapus/{id_simpanan}', [SimpananController::class,'destroy']);

Comment: It's because you are getting the wrong ID in your modal in view. In the modal, from where do you know that the ID you get from is the table row you want?

Comment: oh.. that means the modal should go into foreach?
let me try

Comment: No, don't put the modal inside the foreach, because you will produce a lot of unnecessary modals, instead, use JavaScript to pass the ID to the modal when the delete button the table is clicked.

Comment: can you show me a sample script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the table you can add an event listener to listen for click on the button like this to call a JavaScript function that gets the ID:

```
<td>
  <div class="text-right">
      <a
        href="/simpanan/edit/{{$data->id_simpanan}}"
        class="btn btn-sm btn-success"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Edit
      </a>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"
        data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#modal-sm"
        onclick="pass_id_to_modal({{ $data->id }})"
      >
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Hapus
      </button>
    </div>
</td>
```

Also, for the modal, we can set "#" for href because we are going to set it dynamically, instead we can add a ID for the button to be accessible via the JavaScript function like this:

```
<!-- modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Yakin hapus data?</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Data yang dihapus tidak dapat kembali&hellip;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
          <a id="modal_delete_link" href="#" methode="post" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
            <i class="fas fa-user"></i> Hapus
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, you can either create a JS file or add the following function inside the View itself to handle the ID transfer the modal:

```
function pass_id_to_modal(id) {
  var delete_button = document.getElementById("modal_delete_link");
  delete_button.href = "/simpanan/hapus/" + id;
}
```

Comment: wow its work...
but the id onClick that you showed, I replaced it with id_simpanan, because I have changed the default id to the sid_simpanan.... thank you very much my friend :)

Comment: My pleasure, I would appreciate an Upvote as well since you have accepted it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try this 
$simpanan=Simpanan::where('id_simpanan',$id);
        $simpanan->delete();
```

the above code will delete all simpanan with given id .

```
$simpanan=Simpanan::find($id)->delete();
```

the above code will delete one row matched with given id .

Comment: does not work
deleted data is still other data with the smallest id